# Each child should have a prop warning

Tags: reactjs, list

Why am I getting this warning: `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` , when I am in fact adding key in the map function?

```
const fieldsArr =
        effectsTextArr.map((effectsText, i) => {
                const style = effectsText.length === 1 ? fieldStyle1Icon : fieldStyle2Icons
                return (
                    <div style={style} key={i} onClick={() => playerStateContext.handleClickOnRelic(effectsArr[i], i)}>
                        {playerState.relics[i] ? effectsText : <Shiny/>}
                    </div>
                )
            }
        )
```

Source array:

```
const effectsTextArr = [
        [<Jewel/>],
        [<Jewel/>],
        [<Coin/>, <div style={overLapStyle}><Weapon/></div>],
        [<Weapon/>],
        [<Explore/>, <div style={overLapStyle}><Text/></div>],
        [<Coin/>, <div style={overLapStyle}><Text/></div>],
        [<Coin/>],
        [<Explore/>],
        [<Draw1Card/>]
    ]
```

Am I supposed to add keys to the source array elements too? Is it wrong to use JSX elements is this way? I use them to store icons that I use in different places of my app.

Answer (score 2):

`effectsText` is an array of JSX elements, it still requires assigning an unique key to it.

```
{playerState.relics[i] ? 
     effectsText :  // here an array is passed and every elem requires a key
     <Shiny />
}
```

So instead of directly passing it as a variable, you could map over it and assign a key:

```
{effectsText.map((nested) => (
   <React.Fragment key={someUniqId}>{nested}</React.Fragment>
)}
```